# ActionBar list naviation with alternative display

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to recreate an aspect of the Action Bar in Google Calendar - specifically I want to display a title ("May 2012" in the image) which when clicked provides a drop down menu, of which the title is not a part of.

Has anyone got a way of doing this - ideally I'm looking for something which will work in ActionBarSherlock, to provide backward compatibility.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Was trying to achieve the exact same result today and of course the best is to look at [Google's very own Calendar Sources here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar) (thanks [Nicolas Klein](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104906570725395999813/about)).

The code you want to look at is used in AllInOneActivity, which uses a custom Adapter (CalendarViewAdapter extends BaseAdapater) and two different layouts (actionbar_pulldown_menu_button.xml and actionbar_pulldown_menu_top_button.xml)

They basically inflate the menu layout in the getDropDownView method of the adapter and the top menu layout in the getView method.